# Google Map Not Working In IIS

Tags: asp.net

I have used Google map in my application using the DLL Artem.Google.
its work very well on local application in visual studio and in IIS through another PC or same PC.
like examples:http://192.168.2.252/MySite/Gmap.aspx
but while publishing in public IP

it gives error like :
"this website needs a different Google MAPS API key.a new key can be generated at http://Code.google.com/apis/maps/."

I Tested The same Page in other site hosted in same IIS Server but its not working..
While placing the page in wamp server its working.

Answer (score 2):

When you're using Google map api v2.0, you need different API key for another URL. Try to switch to api v3.0 or generate new key for your new url.